# What evaluation mechanism is behind Mathematica support for multiple definitions of a function? What is the benefit of this?

Tags: function-construction, core-language, localization

I am studying the question [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)
Up to now, I have fulfilled some of the parts but yet don't understand which this problem is related to?
Consider the following code:

In my notebook, which is a test notebook to try out the codes in the above question, I have defined function **f** in 3 different places with the following sequence:

```
f[x_] := Expand[x^2](*SetDelayed*)
f[a + b]        
(* a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 *)

f[x_] := Sqrt[x] /; x > 0(*Condition[patt,test]*)
f[2]        
(* Sqrt[2] *)

f[-2]        
(* f[-2] *)

f[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sin[t^3], {t, 0, x}]  
f[2]        
(* Sqrt[2] *)
```

Getting the answer $\sqrt{2}$ for $f[2]$ clued that there exists a problem and function $f$ is not updated by its new definition. So I wrote this code:

```
?f  

Global`f
f[x_]:=Sqrt[x]/;x>0

f[x_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[Sin[t^3],{t,0,x}]

f[x_]:=Expand[x^2]
```

And to see which of these definitions will be used each time the function $f$ is evoked, I wrote:

```
f[2]        
(* Sqrt[2] *)

f[a + b]  

(* a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 *)

f[6]        
(* Sqrt[6] *)

f[-2]        
(* 0.451948 *)
```

Now a few questions rise up:

1. which characteristic of the Wolfram language causes this (commands
   not having side effects, precedence of operators, .....,any thing
   else)?
2. What is the application of that characteristic in math that
   convinced the wolfram language developers to design the language
   this way?
3. Do we have to `clear` , `Unset` or `UnsetDelay` variables and functions each
   time we finish our work with them?
4. Is there a way to tell wolfram language explicitly which definition
   of $f$ should be used?
5. Is their something like `local variable`, `private function` in
   Wolfram language that enables us define variables just when we want
   to use them and better manage the memory (just like C++)?

Comment: Mathematica is trying to use first the most specific definition availalbe. In particular when you type `?f` you see `Sqrt` definition appears before `NIntegrate` that It does not always correlated with the order the definitions are introduced. So yes just add `Clear[f]` before each new definition.

Comment: As for (5), you can read about the scoping constructs available in Wolfram Language [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html). They perform garbage-collection.

Comment: C++ is probably the one of worst languages to use as a mental model when trying learn _Mathematica_ semantics.

Comment: See [The Ordering of Definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheOrderingOfDefinitions.html) "When you make a sequence of definitions in the Wolfram System, some may be more general than others. The Wolfram System follows the principle of trying to put more general definitions after more specific ones. This means that special cases of rules are typically tried before more general cases."

Answer (score 11):

1. *Mathematica* works by rewriting expressions. Each of your definitions involves a different condition triggering the rewrite.
2. Rewriting is the essence of symbolic mathematics. Mastery of this in *Mathematica* will allow you to implicitly delay evaluation until enough is known about the expression to evaluate it, efficiently evaluate special cases, terminate recursion cleanly, and much more.
3. If the conditions and patterns associated with a definition match a previous definition, you override that definition. Otherwise, you're adding a new definition which will apply in the defined circumstances.
4. *Mathematica* chooses the most specific definition that applies.
5. *Mathematica* has a number of scoping constructs including `With`, `Module`, and `Block`.

Answer (score 6):

The use of pattern matching to inform *Mathematica* of which of several function definitions to apply to a function call is extremely powerful in practice. For one, it allows tail-recursive functions, functions which are essentially as efficient as iterators, to be defined. For two, it allows functions to exclude argument forms that are not acceptable, which can be used to make *Mathematica*, despite having untyped variables, more picky about arguments that C++.

Here is a simple example that defines a factorial function that only accepts positive integers and which is implemented using tail recursion.

```
g[1, val_] := val
g[k_, val_] := g[k - 1, k val]
fact[k_Integer /; k > 0] := g[k, 1]
fact[___] := $Failed
```